# Как можно откатить версию Visual Studio Community?

Tags: visual-studio

Я использовал Visual Studio 2022 17.7.0 и всё было отлично, потом мне пришло обновление и я его скачал, но после этого мой проект стал работать не так, как раньше, причем код я вообще не трогал.
 Я нашел [эту страницу](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history), но там нету Community версии.
Я еще знаю, что можно откатиться из под Visual Studio Installer, но там я мог откатится на версию 17.6.5, а мне нужна именно 17.7.0

Comment: Наверное стоило бы задать вопрос про *"мой проект стал работать не так, как раньше"*. Возможно вам необходимо выполнить какие-то действия по миграции проекта и перенастройке компонентов.

Comment: Похоже, что в Installer'e Community версии нет возможности отката к предыдущей версии. Eсть [аргумент командной строки rollback для отката](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#rollback-command-and-command-line-parameters), но не понятно будет ли он работать в Community версии. P.S.: поправьте заголовок вопроса добавив в него Community, а в вопрос версию на которую обновились.